# Extract data from nested lists

Tags: python, list, function

So I have lists which give width, height, x coordinate and style type of flowers. The lists look like this:

```
list_5 = [[ 43, 440, -120, 'type_D'],
         [150, 380, -270, 'type_A'],
         [140, 495,  -30, 'type_B'],
         [180, 450,  300, 'type_E'],
         [40,  890, 660, 'type_A'],
         [170, 390,  300, 'type_D'],
         [140, 360,   30, 'type_F'],
         [160, 280, -160, 'type_C'],
         [130, 440, -420, 'type_F'],
         [260, 330, -390, 'type_B'],
         [170, 130, -270, 'type_E'],
         [340, 190,  -50, 'type_D'],
         [200, 210,  265, 'type_C'],
         [900, 320,  440, 'type_F'],
         [130, 200, -450, 'type_A']]
```

I need help taking the data from this list and using it in a function to generate the different types given the `width`, `height` and `x` coordinate (which could be anything).

For example if `Type_A` had a `width` of `30`, `height` of `30` and `x` coordinate of `30`, I would need these generated for style A (which may be red and have certain petals and textures).

So far I've created this:

```
def draw_flowers(parameter_list):
    pass

draw_flowers(list_5)
```

I don't know how to extract the data from the list in order to give the certain types the dimensions in the list.

Comment: A detailed input and output example might be helpful.

Comment: It looks like you accidentally deleted most of your question content.  I've restored it; the answers don't make much sense without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most pythonic way to write a switch-case is using a dictionary:

```
def styleA(width, height, x):
    # do something

def styleB(width, height, x):
    # do something

def styleC(width, height, x):
    # do something

flower_function = {
    'type_A': styleA,
    'type_B': styleB,
    'type_C': styleC
}

def draw_flowers(parameter_list):
    for width, height, x, type in parameter_list:
        flower_function[type](width, height, x)
```

Comment: what exactly is this statement doing: 

for type, width, height, x in parameter_list:
        flower_function[type](width, height, x) 

because it gives me this error when i try to run a test: 

building_function[type](width, height, x)
KeyError: 50

i printed the values of width height and x in the StyleA function and it gave me (490,-470,Style_F) when it should have given (50,490,-470)

Comment: yes, sorry, my fault. Check now. It is list unpacking, for example doing `a, b = [1, 2]` is the same as `a = 1` and `b = 2`. So I'm looping through your lines and unpacking them in the components. Then I use `type` to index the `flower_function` and get the corresponding function. Finally I can pass that function the other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the dispatching is not based on the `type` parameter only. But might imply arbitrary complex rules:

> *"`Type_A` had a `width` of 30, `height` of 30 and `x` coordinate of 30 => `styleA`"*

Maybe you need some kind of [multimethods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch), but based not only on types, but on values too ?

For more basic usage, that might do the trick:

```
def styleA(width, height, x, type):
    pass

def styleA_ExtraSize(width, height, x, type):
    pass

def defaultStyle(width, height, x, type):
    pass

def dispatch(width, height, x, type):
    # The dispatcher is the key element. 
    # Taking benefit of python first-class functions,
    # it will return one function or the other based on your rules
    #
    # Rules might be arbitrary complex as in this example:

    if width == 30 and height == 30 and x == 30 and type == 'type_A':
        return styleA
    elif width > 100 and height > 100 and type == 'type_A':
        return styleA_ExtraSize
    # elif
    #     ...
    # elif
    #     ...
    else:
        return defaultStyle

def draw_flowers(lst):
    for item in lst:
        handler = dispatch(*item)
        handler(*item)

draw_flowers(list_5)
```

The main advantage of this approach is it clearly separated the dispatcher (that have knowledge of your "rule") from the function that *applies* the various style. It is a must to ease testing.